# Xiaomi Miui 13 - User authentication required on KeyGenerator.generateKey()

Tags: android, android-keystore, xiaomi

I found a crash on Crashlytics for my app.
The crash statistics show that 93% of the affected devices are Xiaomi, with 49% on Android 13, 42% on Android 12, and 9% on Android 11.
I use encryption to save my data, and the key is generated in the following mode:

```
val generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore")
generator.init(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        alias,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
    ).apply {
    setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
    setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
    setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
    setUserAuthenticationParameters(0, KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG or KeyProperties.AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
    setKeySize(256)
}.build())
generator.generateKey()
```

The crash is in the last line

> Fatal Exception: java.security.ProviderException: Keystore key
> generation failed
> at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.engineGenerateKey(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:413)
> at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey(KeyGenerator.java:612)
>
> Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: User authentication
> required
> at android.security.KeyStore2.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore2.java:330)
> at android.security.KeyStoreSecurityLevel.handleExceptions(KeyStoreSecurityLevel.java:57)
> at android.security.KeyStoreSecurityLevel.generateKey(KeyStoreSecurityLevel.java:145)
> at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.engineGenerateKey(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:400)
> at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey(KeyGenerator.java:612)

I didn't find anything on Google or on Stack Overflow.
The BiometricPrompt is needed when I use this key with a cipher, so the "User authentication required" problem doesn't make sense.
Does anyone have an explanation for this crash?